# copying then deleting a dynamic array

Tags: c++

My program is crashing throwing a memory heap corruption error.
The problematic code block is described just bellow  - the problem appears at "delete [] p;" bellow
the aim of this block code is to resize an array (items - defined in the class header)
In order to do that, 
 1. I allocate a new array (copy) with the new appropriate capacity.
 2. I copy the old array (items) into the new (resized) array "copy".
 3. Then I try to delete copy since I don't need it anymore 
I'm certainly doing an error in the last point.
How to do that correctly ? - meaning how to release the memory handled by "copy" correctly
avoiding memory leak?

```
template <class Item> void MinPQ<Item>::resize(int capacity)
{
    Item *copy = new Item[capacity];//capacity = stack size


    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        copy[i] = items[i];
    }
    Item *p = items;
    items = copy;
    delete[] p;

    p = NULL;//avoid dangling pointer
}
```

Item is defined in the class as follow:

```
template <class Item> class MinPQ
{
    private:

        Item *items;
        int queueSize;
        int N;

        void resize(int capacity);
        bool greater(int i, int j);
        void exch(int i, int j);
        void swim(int k);
        void sink(int k);

    public:

        MinPQ();
        ~MinPQ();
        void insert(Item item);
        Item delMin();
        void print();
        inline int size(){return N;}
        inline bool isEmpty(){return N == 1;}
};
```

The constructor and destructor are defined bellow:

```
template <class Item> MinPQ<Item>::MinPQ()
{
    queueSize = 2;
    N = 0;
    items = new Item[queueSize];
}

template <class Item> MinPQ<Item>::~MinPQ()
{
    delete [] items;
    items = NULL;
}
```

Comment: 1. Your class seems to violate the rule of three. 2. Just use `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: You forgot to give us the code that actually *calls* the function you show here. However, if `queuesize` does what I think it does, you should set it to `capacity` in that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was not caused by the fact that I have not defined a copy constructor or I have not overloaded the =operator. 
It was caused by the fact that I was accessing undefined memory chunk of an allocated array. 
Clearly: I defined an array of N elements but I used only says N-10 out of N. 
At a certain point in the program I do a swap between some of the defined N-10 elements and some of the undefined 10 elements. This is a bug that causes a crash.
Anyway, thanks all for answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely due to the fact that you are not defining a copy-constructor nor a copy-assignment operator, and are (somewhere) attempting to copy your queue.  That will copy the values of your pointers, but when it goes out of scope, will free the memory.  Then the other copy goes out of scope and attempts to free memory that has already been freed.

You can fix that by following the [Rule of 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)